# play framework secure config

Tags: security, session, playframework

When I set `application.session.secure=true` in application.conf
I can't store anything in the session.  Can anyone tell me how this is supposed to work?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Your question needs clarifying and more details. Did you exceed the limit of data (4k) in your cookie? Were you sending your requests  through https? Does the answer below helped or required more explaination?

Answer (score 9):

`session.secure=true` only tells the client to send the cookie only over https (not over http).

Remember that Play! is a stateless framework.
Nothing should be kept in the session. If you need to store things, use the cookie.